# How can I make the set converted from a list display in the same order as the list?

Tags: python

```
mylist=['P','y','t','h','o','n']
print(set(mylist))
```

Convert list to set, but the set that I got does not follow the order like the list does

```
{'h', 'y', 'o', 't', 'P', 'n'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't since sets do not have order.

You can, however, convert the set back to a sorted list, using the original list's indexes as the sorting key:

```
mylist = ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
print(sorted(set(mylist), key=mylist.index))
```

outputs

```
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

This obviously makes more sense if the original list contains duplicated items:

```
mylist = ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'o', 'n']
print(sorted(set(mylist), key=mylist.index))
```

also outputs

```
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

A small caveat arises if the original list contains duplicated elements in non-consecutive indexes, due to the fact that `list.index` returns the index of the first occurrence that it finds.

```
mylist = ['c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a']
print(sorted(set(mylist), key=mylist.index))
```

outputs

```
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: in general, `sorted(set(mylist), key=mylist.index)` is inadvisable, it can degrade to quadratic time